# Git Flow: Managing Main-Develop Version Discrepancy After Feature Merges

Tags: git-flow

```
*   cde53d9 (origin/main, main) Merge branch 'develop'
|\
| *   7d94faa (HEAD -> develop) Merge branch 'feature/road-view' into develop
```

After merging the feature/road-view branch into the develop branch and subsequently merging develop into main, the main branch is now ahead of develop by one commit. In this situation, if I need to create new feature branches from the develop branch and continue working, should I merge main back into develop, aligning the versions, before proceeding with the work?

Answer (score 0):

> should I merge main back into develop, aligning the versions, before proceeding with the work?

No. Don't worry about the extra merge commit on `main`. The states of `develop` and `main` are the same; only a new merge-commit is missing on `develop`. So, you *can* merge `main` back into `develop`, but you don't *have* to. However, if you merge a `hotfix` into `main` that isn't yet on `develop`, then you must merge the `hotfix` (or better yet `main`) back down to `develop` as well.

That being said, note that standard Git Flow doesn't have a scenario where `develop` is directly merged into `main`. Instead an in-between `release` branch would be used. If you find yourself not needing a `release` branch, then you may not need the complexity of Git Flow. If this is your case, you could consider renaming `develop` to `main` and tag your releases so you know when you deployed. This workflow is simpler, and is commonly called "Feature Branch workflow", and also "GitHub Flow".